# how to add tree json in combobox

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have JSON same `{id: 1 , name:A , Chidlren:[{id:2, parentID: 1, name: C}]}`, how to load in combobox same tree using Sencha Architect.

Comment: could you specify your question? do you want to share a store petween a tree panel and a combobox?

Comment: i have tree store and load data in tree panel success, now i want load in combobox i think must config in combobox. I search have method use tree.combobox. but i don't know use in sencha architect

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, please mark it as solved and/or vote it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a treepanel inside a combobox?

If so, you can use this ux: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.TreePicker

In SA you have to

- set the **userAlias** (xtype) to **treepicker**.
- copy the source code from TreePicker to ext/ux/TreePicker.js